# How to rebase my local commits on top of new commits in base branch in remote

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm trying the bread-and-butter usecase of `git rebase` and it's not working as expected.

[According to a guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase), when there are new commits to your feature's base branch in remote: *"You want to get the latest updates to the `master` branch in your `feature` branch, but you want to keep your branch's history clean so it appears as if you've been working off the latest `master` branch."*

Expectation is that after rebasing (`git rebase master`), the commits in feature branch are re-written. But reality is local-feature branch ends up 1 behind and 2 ahead than remote-feature branch (`[feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]`). [See bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt#examples) for format.

I also tried `git rebase --onto <SHA of master's head>`. Similar result `[feature/123 ↓·1↑·1|✔]`.

So obviously both `pull` and `push` are rejected (see #4 below). What do I do next?

Notes:

- There are no conflicts/overlaps between changes in feature and master. So no conflict resolution etc.
- I know I can use `merge`. I want "clean history" (without merge commit), so want to use `rebase`.
- I've read following and many more:

  - [Rebasing, some changes local and new remote commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698246/rebasing-some-changes-local-and-new-remote-commits)
  - [Pushing to remote after locally rebasing commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096170/pushing-to-remote-after-locally-rebasing-commits)

---

[image]

A working example:

##### 1. Create first commit in `master`

```bash
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com/~kash/rebase-test.git
cd rebase-test/
date > only-changed-in-master.txt
git add only-changed-in-master.txt 
git commit -m 'creation'
git push
```

##### 2. Create a feature branch from `master` and add a commit to `feature`

```bash
git checkout -b feature/123
date > only-changed-in-feature.txt
git add only-changed-in-feature.txt 
git commit -m 'creation'
git push --set-upstream origin feature/123
```

##### 3. Add new changes to `master`

```bash
git checkout master
date > new-file-in-master.txt
git add new-file-in-master.txt 
git commit -m 'adding new file in master'
git push
```

##### 4. Rebase `feature` onto `master` to bring latest changes from master in feature

```bash
✔ ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123|✔]
$ git rebase master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature/123.
✔ ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]
$ git push
To ssh://bitbucket.company.com/~kash/rebase-test.git
 ! [rejected]        feature/123 -> feature/123 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://bitbucket.company.com/~kash/rebase-test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
✘-1 ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]
$ git pull
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
✘-128 ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]
$
```

##### 5. Rebase `feature` onto latest commit SHA from `master`'s `git log`

```bash
$ git checkout feature/123
$ git reset --hard origin/feature/123
HEAD is now at c3a8f2c creation
✔ ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123|✔]
```

```bash
git checkout master
git log 
git checkout feature/123
...
$ git rebase --onto 5e3a2ed1f3657e7cde741d014a2c86afd99f1d92
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature/123.
✔ ~/workspaces/rebase-test [feature/123 ↓·1↑·1|✔]
$
```

Comment: an aside, whoever gave you this information about clean history is wrong.  It's not the truth, and what you will create by rebasing wildly every second is going to produce a useless history that is a lie, where git-blame can't be used.  You need to be careful before you do down a rabbit hole of 'always' rebasing and make sure you understand the implications. You can also get a clean history at merge time by rebasing after a code review, or by performing a squash merge, etc.  Thats a deep topic i will avoid going further into here.

Comment: @UpAndAdam, "whoever gave you this information about clean history" -> I quoted the source (altassian.com). But every other source also says the same (it'll create "new commits" to replace old commits). For me the appeal is simply in cases where someone merges a PR unrelated to my ongoing feature on remote and then I have to keep creating a merge commit for it, although there is no conflict/relation.

Comment: agreed, for the scenario you describe that's what i do... but if there are major changes i have to cope with. i prefer to merge them in. otherwise my history goes to crap

Comment: Whoever gave you this information about clean history is absolutely correct. Rebasing gives a much cleaner history than springkling in random merges into the feature branch. I have no idea why someone would claim that rebasing would in any way prevent `git blame` from working because that is factually false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out, your push is failing because it is diverging from `origin/feature/123` and the remedy is to force push (use `--force-with-lease`). But I want to start by explaining in detail what the git prompt actually means since I think there is some misconception.

---

Replaying the steps to step 4 (including) gives the following history, displayed with `gitk --all` (pink overlays added with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)):

[image: gitk screenshot]

which clearly shows the meaning of `[feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]`: your local `feature/123` branch is

- one (remote) commit behind `origin/feature/123`
- two (local) commits ahead of `origin/feature/123`.

And I want to stress that this has **nothing** to do with where the `main` or `master` branch is. Yes, that branch was incidentally used to arrive at this point but the same could also happen even if `feature/123` was the only branch existing. Replaying up to (including) step 3 and then running

```bash
git checkout feature/123
date >> only-changed-in-feature.txt
git add only-changed-in-feature.txt
git commit --amend -m 'creation modified'
date >> only-changed-in-feature.txt
git add only-changed-in-feature.txt
git commit -m 'new commit'
```

*also* results in `[feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]` and gives the following history:

[image: gitk screenshot 2]

Where `main` is (or if it even exists) in this scenario is irrelevant.

---

So your rebase operation was 100% successful and resulted in no problems by itself. The only issue you have is the divergingness of the `feature/123` branch. This now needs a force push to resolve, and there are very good reasons for cautioning against doing this willy nilly without a careful thought about what the consequences will be. But it is absolutely not a you should never, never ever do this thing.

There are two potential problems with force push

- you might silently discard/loose commits pushed by other collaborators
- other collaborators are required to perform "recovery" that is not necessarily trivial

So right of the bat, if you are the only person creating commits on branch `feature/123` then there really is no issues with force pushing it.

---

To go a bit deeper on the two issues, imagine Alice and Bob working together on branch `somebranch`. At the beginning of the day both starts by pulling, and the branch contains commits `C1 -> C2 -> C3`.

Alice works on completing a feature, and creates two commits `A1` and `A2` and pushes those so that the origin repository now contains `C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> A1 -> A2`.

Bob on the other hand has just updated the compiler and discovers that commit `C3` does not compile with the new version of the compiler. He spends some time figuring out what the issue is. When arriving at a solution he amends the commit so it does compile, replacing `C3` with a new `B1` commit.

Bob has not run `git fetch` since he started (after all he has been busy figuring out why the code does not compile!) so when he runs

```bash
git push origin --force somebranch
```

this is virtually identical to

```bash
git push origin --delete somebranch
git push origin somebranch
```

and the origin repo then ends up containing commits `C1 -> C2 -> B1` and by that Alice's two `A1` and `A2` commits were discarded and lost by this force push.

*This is the big bad danger of force push that people rightfully are worried about.*

---

There is a much safer alternative to `--force` called `--force-with-lease` that would prevent Bob from discarding Alice's two commits in the above scenario. However depending on when `git fetch` is run (**and notice that tools and editors (like vscode) might run `git fetch` in the background behind your back!**) you still might accidentally override other peoples commits so there is an [additional `--force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/23118) option you ought to use together with `--force-with-lease`.

Alternatively you can supply your expectancy of the remote head directly as an value to the `--force-with-lease` option like

```bash
git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/somebranch:<expected-remote-sha> origin somebranch
```

I agree with Devin Rhode that this probably is the [safest way to force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879323/23118), and would recommend doing this for "unusual"/important cases (for instance force pushing the `main` branch).

For just updating after rebases on a feature branch that only you work on, creating and using an alias

```ini
[alias]
    forcepush = push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes
```

is perfectly fine.

---

The second issue is recovery. Say Bob used `--force-with-lease`, detected that Alice had done some work and then incorporated those commits (hurray, no loss of commits!). So Bob pushes his updates, and the remote repo now contains `C1 -> C2 -> B1 -> B2 -> B3`, where `B1` is the fixed `C3` commit, and `B2` and `B3` corresponds to `A1` and `A2` just with different parents.

Meanwhile Alice has started on a new feature and created a new `A3` commit locally, so her repo looks like `C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> A1 -> A2 -> A3`. She gets to know that Bob fixed something related to a new compiler version and wants to get that fix in. To do that she has to

- [temporary check in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) her outstanding changes (no, `git stash` [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118)).

```bash
git commit -am "==== save ===="    # A4
```

- Retrieve Bob's changes and inspect the history to see what she needs to do to recover

```bash
git fetch origin
gitk --all &
```

- Update her `somebranch` branch to be on top of Bob's latest `origin/somebranch` commits.

Just running the two argument version of rebase<sup>1</sup>

```bash
git rebase origin/somebranch somebranch  # Will almost guaranteed trigger conflict
git reset HEAD^  # Undo A4 back to uncommitted changes
```

**might** work, however this will trigger a git conflict due to the difference between `C3` and `B1` which is unrelated to what Alice worked on but suddenly she gets to resolve that conflict anyhow... And even when successfully resolving conflicts there is a high chance of ending up with phantom dummy commit that maybe just contains a small (duplicated) part of conflicting commits, e.g. Alice starts with

`C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A4`

and should end up with

`C1 -> C2 -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> A3' -> A4'`

but actually ends up with

`C1 -> C2 -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> C3' -> A3' -> A4'`

where `C3'`<sup>2</sup> is a commit with some artifact of some automatic (or incorrect manual) conflict resolvement which then needs to be removed with interactive rebase after the rebase is done.

So the much better way to run the rebase here is to [use the three argument version of rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75268248/23118)<sup>3</sup>:

```bash
git rebase --onto origin/somebranch A2 somebranch
git reset HEAD^  # Undo A4 back to uncommitted changes
```

because this then skips the commits whose conflicts are already resolved.
Depending on what changes are between `C3` and `B1` this *might* cause conflicts for the new `A3'` and `A4'` commits, but this would be unavoidable under any circumstances. The three argument rebase command is the most conflictless way to do this.

As you can see, this does require some skill level on Alice's part beyond the very basic git commands, although it is quite manageable once you learn it. But some people will struggle with this so this is something to watch out for.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should [**never** just use the one argument version of rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113010/23118).

<sup>2</sup> It is common in mathematics (and elsewhere) to add `'` to a variable to indicate it is transformed in some way, e.g. `X -> X'` for some kind of modification. I am using this here to not let different commits use the same name even though they have identical content, their parents are different and hence have different hash ids.

<sup>3</sup>
So `git rebase --onto origin/somebranch A2 somebranch` means rebase branch `somebranch` from (**not including**) commit `A2` on top of `origin/somebranch`.

Comment: absolutely fantastic explanation that explains so many other nuances in a fantastic manner.  Loved the `with-lease` explanation, and I learned something new with the `force-if-includes`.  Take my upvote kind sir

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. The tracking information is correctly indicating your relation to your tracking branch `origin/feature/123` one old commit (already pushed; pre-rebase) and one or two new commits in your branch (post-rebase; the count includes the commits from master).

**Update**  (I didn't see your failed push in the midst of your logs especially since you didn't ask about it.)

You have to `force` push with `git push --force` or `git push -f` because you are doing something git says you shouldn't normally do which is rewrite history of a published branch.

(I'm not sure exactly why the second routine gave you only one commit but I suspect it's not right you should check to make sure that your whole branch came along. there shouldnt have been a difference between using the branch name master and it's sha1, but in either case you should have used origin/master no need to check out to get its hash either, just do `git log origin/master`)

Comment: 1. Ok, lets say it's doing what it's supposed to, then what's the next step? Can't pull or push, so what do I do? -------- 2. I said _"local-feature branch ends up 1 behind and 2 ahead than remote-feature branch ([feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]"_ -------- 3. step 4 and 5 in OP produce different results `[feature/123 ↓·1↑·2|✔]` vs `[feature/123 ↓·1↑·1|✔]`. I thought they do the same. But I don't really care, seems like #4 is the correct way.

Comment: you `push --force` or `push -f`.... also dont rebase on `master` rebase on `origin/master`

Comment: Thanks, yes, `--force` is teh answer. Because in this case "I know" that I've re-written the history for this branch and my local history is the correct on and remote history is obsolete. --- I, as a rule of thumb, don't use `--force` so never thought in that direction.

Comment: if you want to be even more secure you can use --force-with-lease  which will only work if you also have the  same matching view of what origin/<your_branch> is as the server to make sure you dont force push over someone else who just force pushed etc... i do that as my default force push variety to make sure that i'm always force pushing from the right updated place and that im not destroying commits i dont know about... unless i absolutely intend to when that fails and ive checked everything etc...   force pushing always makes me feel dirty. `with lease` makes it a little less so

Answer (score 0):

`rebase` is a purely *local* operation (like most Git operations). That's what Git is telling you: there is one old commit (already pushed; pre-rebase) and two new commits in your branch (post-rebase; the count includes the commits from master).

To update the branch in the remote repository, you must push your rewritten commits. Force pushing is required, because you lose history when pushing (the old, pre-rebase commits are lost).