# Git desktop - why I have Pull origin?

Tags: git, merge, pull, staging

I just did "merge pull request" from my staging to main branch (and then "deployment via git" on server). Everything shows fine on the live site. But why then Pull origin is showed on my staging branch if I just merged from that one to live? I'm afraid to blow-up something. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you the only one working on `staging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you look at the history with `gitk --all &`<sup>1</sup> you should see relatively easily that your `staging` branch is 14 commits behind the `origin/staging` branch.

What the tool is suggesting with "pull origin" <sup>2</sup>  is to bring your local `staging` branch up to date with the `origin/staging` branch, and since your local `staging` branch does not have any un-published local changes this will be a trivial fast-forward merge (in which your local `staging` branch is just moved forward to the commit `origin/staging` is pointing to).

Your situation is much simpler than the example I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) but you might gain some understanding on how multiple updates to a branch from different actors can result in conflicts.

In your case "merge pull request" done by your git server is the another actor and you do not have a conflict, only your local branch is a bit out of date. But sooner of later you will experience this, so in any case it is good to be prepared and I think looking into this aspect will help you decipher your current situation.

---

<sup>1</sup> And you should use `gitk --all &` all the time regardless of this issue! No matter what this Git desktop program claims to be and provide, `gitk` is superior in its features of visualizing, and you should use that as your **primary** history viewing tool.

<sup>2</sup> Which I find incredibly imprecise and almost misleading. Git will perform pull operation on a *branch* and not a *remote*!

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. I will try gitk. Just one more question - is there any way to see what will i pull before I click Pull origin?

Comment: `git pull` is a combination of two things, `git fetch` + `git merge`. So you can run `git fetch` manually and then inspect what the history looks like with `gitk --alll`.