# How to Remove or Modify a Previously Removed Git Commit That Has Been Reintroduced

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase

I recently encountered a Git issue that has caused some issues, and I'm seeking some advice on how to resolve it. Here's the situation:

I was working on our repository and accidentally pushed a commit using my personal username instead of my work account. To rectify this, I removed the commit from the Git history and redid the work. Everything appeared fine at that point—the commit was no longer visible on Visual Studio or Bitbucket, and the work was still done as intended.

However, a fellow group member later pushed to the repository and somehow managed to reintroduce the previously removed commit. To make matters worse, this commit is no longer the latest one, and several branches have been added since then. It has also been merged into the main branch.

I would like to remove this commit permanently, or at the very least change the username and email associated with it, as it contains personal information and it's obviously not professional to have a thing like that sitting around forever. I've come across [this](https://nam11.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fconfluence.atlassian.com%2Fbitbucketserverkb%2Fhow-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html&data=05%7C01%7Ckrcooke%40crimson.ua.edu%7C7462f4e259564e37602d08dbc9f3b093%7C2a00728ef0d040b4a4e8ce433f3fbca7%7C0%7C0%7C638325820703020934%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=3dCuTPRDG2iSRjRqE2sQjb%2FPB2u%2F2uLCd9lduwvfc4Y%3D&reserved=0) article on Bitbucket, which suggests using rebasing to address this issue. However, I've never rebased before, and I'm concerned about potentially breaking anything, especially given the number of branches and the fact that it's been merged into the main branch.

My question is: Is there anything I can do at this point to permanently remove or edit this commit, or am I stuck having to deal with it?

Any guidance or step-by-step instructions on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to remove the commit when I first made it, which worked, until a group member pushed and somehow brought it back. Now I'm not sure how to fix this without potentially breaking a lot of things.

Comment: `until a group member pushed and somehow brought it back` This is an unintended consequence of force pushing. I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) related to that recently that you probably will find useful, and you should definitely advocate for absolutely everyone using `--force-with-lease` instead of just `--force`, which can easily be achieved by using the `forcepush` alias described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there's probably other ways of handling this, but this is what I do when I accidentally push to Bitbucket, which requires a bit of legwork, however, I can predictably understand what happens with granular control:

**Backup the faulty branch**

1. Checkout/pull the faulty branch
2. Utilize `git switch -c branch_backup_name` to backup the branch
3. Push the backed up branch to the server

**Remove the local version of the faulty branch on your computer**

```
git branch -D branch_to_fix
```

**Checkout the commit before the faulty one (for example, if 757c47d4 is the commit before the one with your personal account), and rename to branch you are fixing**

```
git checkout 757c47d4
git switch -c branch_to_fix
```

**Remove the faulty branch on the server in Bitbucket**

1. Click branches on the left hand menu to list the branches in Bitbucket
2. Click the 3 vertical dots for context menu
3. Delete the faulty branch (not the backup one)

**Re-add your changes**

1. Edit your codebase
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "Your commit message"`

**Cherry pick the individual commits that you want from the backup branch (your other commits, your coworker's commits, etc)**

It's important to do this in the same order it was originally committed. If you are viewing this in Bitbucket, it will be bottom up by default.

```
git cherry-pick 12345678
git cherry-pick ...
```

**Push your local branch to the server (you may get asked to set the upstream depending on your git settings)**

```
git push
```

---

At this point you should have the faulty backup branch as well as your new branch that you surgically removed the commit from. You can choose to delete the backup branch (as long as everything looks good) if you wish. Your coworkers will need to delete the branch locally with `git branch -D branch_to_fix` and checkout your new branch from the server.

Comment: Is this something I'd have to do for every branch that's been made since it was merged into main? And would I have to delete main too for this to work? It's wild how difficult making even a small change like this is with Git

Comment: No, to reiterate, this is a one size fits all solution with the added safety net of backing up. You can always git checkout <commit>, git switch -c <destination_branch>, and git push -f to force the branch to overwrite if you want. But I don't recommend doing this without at least giving yourself a safety net