# Git: Merges (seemingly) out of nowhere

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

So I created my own feature branch off the `main` branch. No one else checks in to my feature branch.  I *usually* use the Visual Studio git client, but also Source Tree, the GUI and its command line. Whatever git client/sw I use, I keep going through the following cycle:

1. Pull from feature branch - no change, everything up to date
2. Edit source code
3. Stage all changed files
4. Commit (--amend) staged files - a local commit is created
5. VS Git displays "1 outgoing/1 incoming" - *Where did that ***incoming*** change come from?*
6. "Sync" using VS git - a merge commit is created, which merges my changes with a commit I can't make sense of.  Also, Source Tree shows a terrible mess of merges and commits.

Instead of syncing, I've reverted to "push --force-with-lease" on the command line, but that can't be the solution.

Please tell me where I (probably?) did a wrong step.

Comment: That happens because you are _amending_ (and I assume you had already pushed your previous commit to the remote branch) When you amend, you are replacing a commit with another.... so you are **diverging** from the commit that is already in the remote branch. When you do that, you should then force-push into the remote branch so that the old commit is gone, just like in your local branch.

Comment: "incoming" here means one commit on the remote that is not on your branch. This is the commit you just discarded with your amend command. In this case, yes, pushing with force was the logical course of action to set your local version as the better one. (*Aww, @eftshift0, this time you've been quicker :-D Damn.*)

Comment: One can be lucky every once in a while. :-D

Comment: How did you get in the habit of using `--amend` and expecting a totally new commit that doesn't replace the old one?

Comment: That's enough info for an answer. Thanks, both of you!

Comment: if you view your git history with `gitk --all` (**and you should!** It is way better than whatever vscode or sourcetree shows) it should display rather obvious. I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) showing what it looks like with "2 outgoing/1 incoming". And with regards to force pushing, do not use just plain `push --force`, use the `forcepush` alias that uses the safer `push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes` options, also explained in the answer.

Comment: @hlovdal gitk is underrated indeed.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is: It's my own "fault".

Any commit created with `--amend` creates a new commit while *removing* the previous commit from my local repo. But that previous commit still exists on the server. `push`ing to the server encounters this previous commit and causes a merge.

Answer created from the comments of @eftshift0 and @Romain Valeri.

Comment: Good, but to correct one point : pushing when branches diverge does not "cause a merge". No push can merge anything in git. Pushing just replaces a ref with another. When the new ref is not a child (directly or indirectly) of the current ref, the push is disallowed (unless forced).

Comment: It's the amend followed by the pull that creates the merge commit, since `git pull` is basically just shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.