# How do I merge two history commits into one and force push?

Tags: git

Imagine I have a git branch like this, both on local and remote, HEAD is clean.

```
develop  A - B - C - D - E
```

That commit `B` has some sensitive information that I got rid of on commit `C`. Now I realise people can still see the information though commit history. Is there a way to merge commit `B` and `C` into one so people can't see what happend on commit `B`? Force push is allowed.

Desired outcome:

```
develop  A - F - D - E
```

I was thinking using

```
git reset --soft (hash of B)
git commit -m "message"
git push -f # haven't done this
```

But it will get rid of all the history after `B` which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with a rebase interactive.

Something like (already having `develop` checked out):

```
git rebase -i A
```

It will list all commits starting with `B`. Keep `B` as `pick`, then `C` set it to `squash`. Save and exit.... and it should be fixed. And history should look like this:

```
A <- BC <- D <- E <- (develop)
```

`BC` is the squash of `B` and `C`.

If you want to do it *by hand*, then:

```
git checkout B
git restore --source C --worktree --staged -- . # get the contents just like it is in C
git commit --amend --no-edit # or edit if you think the message should be different now
git cherry-pick C..E
# if you like the result....
git checkout -B develop # set the branch over here, we know it exists already, we don't care
```

And then force-push.

Comment: Btw, is there still a way to restore the info from commit `B` again (cache, indices etc)? I want to make sure there's no way it can be restored.

Comment: In your local? It will be eventually disposed of (if there are no references to it)... or you can force garbage collection (need to consider reflog, etc etc). Other people's repos? It gets tricky but _possible_. In a provider? You need to request the object to be removed so you need to contact the provider.

Comment: I think it will be fine as long as the new clones and forks can't see the erased history. And it is on GitHub

Comment: You can check accessibility by trying `git clone url-to-repo the-commit-id`. If the commit is not accessible anymore, it will barf.

Answer (score 0):

For rebase interactive

```
git rebase -i A
```

For force change to remote repository

```
git push origin +develop
```

"+" is shorthand for a force push

Comment: The best and safest way to force push is with `git push  origin --force-with-lease --force-if-includes develop`. To avoid having to write all that every time use a [`forcepush` alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118).