# Git undo force push to remote branch

Tags: git, github, rebase, undo

I need to undo a force push to a remote branch, or apply the previous changes that were merged to the remote branch before the force push from my local.

This is a *release* branch.  The origin *release* had many fixes merged into it that I was not aware of and I did not fetch to my local.  When I pushed new changes from my local *release* branch to the origin, I force-pushed them.  Now the origin release branch doesn't have any of the fixes that were merged into it.

I was able to rebase *most* of the individual commits with `git rebase <COMMIT ID>`, but some of them are returning the error `fatal: no such branch/commit '<COMMIT ID>'`.

I am assuming *git fetch* did not get the entire log? Why would some of these work and some not? They're all relatively recent, within the last ~20 commits pushed to the repo.

Comment: first thing you can do: check your local reflog. Run `git reflog origin/release --format="%h [%gs] %s"` to see what versions of `release` you have fetched at some point. If you see the correct commit in that list, you can force push it again. Check the value that preceeded your `[update by push]` action.

Comment: I never fetched the changes to my local before force-pushing.  I did check git reflog and it didn't show the changes, since I never had them.

Comment: if the commit you are looking for is not there: check the history of your repo on the central remote. On github, there is an "Activity" link (with today's GUI: on the right hand side of the project's landing page), on gitlab, a "Manage > Activity" tab ... You should be able to find a link to the full sha of the previous commit, and fetch that `git fetch origin <complete sha>:refs/heads/back-from-the-dead`

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the way the other engineers merged their changes.  I believe they cherry picked, and the shas that i'm using can't be used to rebase with.  I'm trying to find the right ones but all the PRs only show one sha each.  I may need to copy paste the changes... ugh

Comment: on top of the activity tab, if there are Pull Requests on your git service then your repo keeps a reference to the resulsts of said merge requests. Run `git ls-remote` to visualize that. You can choose to download one of these refs by running `git fetch origin refs/pulls/1234/merge:refs/tags/pr/1234` (<- name the remote ref first, and any name you see fit as a local ref after. In my example, you would create a tag in your local repo)

Comment: And with regards to force pushing, `--force-with-lease --force-if-includes` is your friend to avoid situations like these. Typically [aliased to `forcepush`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution: Get someone else to fix it

Someone else on you team might have a version of the release branch which has all the old changes. Have them force push it.

---

The reflog solution

Look through the reflog of the release branch remote. You do however not have any guarantees that you have the correct state in your reflog since you used `--force` (I don't know the state of the remote branch but want to overwrite it anyway) rather than `--force-with-lease` (only overwrite the state of the remote if it is in the state I know)
If you never had the deleted version try it on a pc where you know it has existed.

---

The "merge it all again" solution

Remember that even if the other developers deleted their branches after merge, if anyone on the team uses `git pull`/`git fetch` without the `--prune` option then they will still have the remote branches locally on their pc.

---

Final comment on `--force`

Don't use `--force`. The only times were a normal push will fail (and `--force` will succeed) is when there are other changes on the branch you are pushing to.
It is useful for rewriting history for branches you yourself own. It will however always cause problems if you are working on a branch with someone else.

I hope any of these will help.

Comment: The solution was to have someone else fix it.  I wanted to do it myself, but it just wasn't realistic.  

The reflog option did not work for me.  

Thank you for your detailed answer with options.