# How to fix two git repositories that have different versions of the github main/master?

Tags: git

I have git on Linux and Windows linked to a github repository. I had been going back and forth by commiting/pushing everything on one before doing a pull for the other before doing modifications and then doing a commit/push from that side.

But now I have done a commit/push on Windows without having commited/pushed all my changes on Linux.

```
~/code/v> git status
On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Using "git pull" give an error message:

```
~/code/v git pull 
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.  
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use git add/rm <file>' 
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit. 
fatal: Exitinq because of an unresolved conflict
```

What is the name for this situation?

I know I could just delete and start over on the Linux side. Is that the easiest way to go?

Found this on another question answer but it's message doesn't show any issue for some reason:

```
~/code/v> git mergetool --tool=vimdiff
No files need merging
```

After doing a "cherry-pick" command (suggested by git or a git frontend)  and then undoing it "git pull" now says:

```
/code/v> git pull
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

> ~/code/v> git config pull.rebase false

```
~/code/v> git pull
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Auto-merging assertions/assertions.v
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in assertions/assertions.v
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: There's no name for the solution, you just do what `git` tells you.  You need to merge upstream into your working copy on your Linux system.  It should give you the exact branch you need to use (e.g., `origin/main`).

Comment: @StephenNewell What commands are involved in "merge upstream"?

Comment: Your error message indicates that you currently have conflicts ("unmerged files") to solve. Run `git status` to confirm that, and fix the conflicts.

Comment: `git merge`, which I'm pretty sure is included in the full error text.  I mostly do `git` on autopilot though, so I could be mistaken on whether it shows this particular command.

Comment: @StephenNewell I included the full error message for what "git pull" gives at this point.

Comment: @Cristik There is 12 answers there with positive upvotes. None of them give what I would call a good explanation of the situation and one solution didn't work for me (git mergetool shown above claimed no issues). But one does show how to just get rid of all the changes on the Linux side so I will do that as it is the easiest to understand.

Comment: You came into this situation, because you did a `git pull` before that stopped due to merge conflicts. Any subsequent `git pull` will now stop with the shown error message and hint that tell you that you must resolve the existing conflicts and make a commit before you can `git pull` again.

Comment: To expand on the `Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged, and have 1 and 8 different commits each` see the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118). In your case here the solution is not a force push, the answer to "How to fix two git repositories that have different versions of the github main?" is `git pull --rebase`.