# Discard some changes/commits made on a branch already merged into master

Tags: git

I've implemented a feature in a branch (let's call it "branch A"), which I successfully merged into the master branch. Subsequently, I made additional commits on master, primarily related to dependencies, which need to be retained.

However, upon reflection, I've realized that there's a better approach to implementing the feature, and I now need to discard some of the changes introduced in "branch A." How should I proceed?

My current plan is to create a new branch (let's name it "branch B") from the current state of the master branch. Then, I intend to revert the specific commits from "branch A" that I no longer require, make the necessary adjustments, and finally merge "branch B" back into master.

Here's a graphical representation of my Git history to aid in understanding the situation:
[image]

Would this approach be the correct way to handle the situation, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: That's a reasonable approach. An alternative would be to not create branch B and make the reverts directly in main. Or to create branch B based on the latest commit of branch A before the merge. Which one is better is a matter of taste (i.e. what do you want the history to look like at the end).

Comment: The reason I'm hesitant to directly revert changes in the main branch is because I'm not completely certain about the viability of the new approach for the feature. As a result, I prefer not to alter what is already functioning effectively.

Comment: The plan sounds good. As a sidenote, remember to list the commits in reverse chronological order for your revert command. You might also want to consider using `-n` to accumulate changes (and resolve conficts) in order to group the entire reverting operation in a single commit at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with interactive rebase. Starting with the following history

[image: gitk --all screenshot 1]

then running

```bash
git branch main-new main
git switch main-new
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges bec79848      # bec79848 = "a commit"
```

brings up the following content in the editor

```
label onto

# Branch branch-a
reset onto
pick 94ed236 another commit
label branch-point
pick 5fa1c41 a commit I don't want to keep
pick fe608b5 another commit I don't want to keep
pick 646b3c3 a commit I want to keep
pick 2d38ac6 another commit I want to keep
label branch-a

reset branch-point # another commit
merge -C a55c036 branch-a # Merge branch 'branch-a'
pick 83b98b1 update dependencies
pick 179e3f3 another commit with small changes
```

which you then trim down to the following by removing the two commits you do not want:

```
label onto

# Branch branch-a
reset onto
pick 94ed236 another commit
label branch-point
pick 646b3c3 a commit I want to keep
pick 2d38ac6 another commit I want to keep
label branch-a

reset branch-point # another commit
merge -C a55c036 branch-a # Merge branch 'branch-a'
pick 83b98b1 update dependencies
pick 179e3f3 another commit with small changes
```

After exiting git will update the history to the following

[image: gitk --all screenshot 2]

where `main-new` is now what you wanted.

If you are happy with the result (including all commits on the branch [runs tests successfully](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test)) and want to make `main` identical to this, then check out `main`, reset to `main-new` and [`forcepush`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) the changes.