Interactive rebase to drop/remove commits from git history does now show the commit to be dropped
I have created this GitHub repository that perfectly reproduces my issue, but I will explain it here as well (but feel free to take a look if anything is unclear!).
I should also state that I'm totally comfortable having vi be my rebase tool, as I don't rebase all that often, and unless it truly makes my life supremely easier, I'd rather hold off downloading, installing and learning a whole new tool just for the ocassional rebase.

In my GitHub project, I have a branch called feature/some-feature, and this branch is several commits ahead of both develop and main (the feature branch was cut from develop, which itself was cut from main).
On the second commit, I messed up and committed sensitive passwords/credentials to a config file:
db.name=fizz
db.port=9000
db.user=buzz
db.password=12345

Whoopsie daisy! Not only do I need to redact db.user's and db.password's values, but I also need to purge the entire commit from git history, otherwise valid credentials will be floating around in source control. Not good for business!
So first I pushed a redacting commit to redact the values, making the config now look like:
db.name=fizz
db.port=9000
db.user=<!redacted!>
db.password=<!redacted!>

But now I need to erase the bad commit from history (commit ID a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597).
So, from my feature/some-feature branch, I run:
git rebase -i a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597

Which brings me to this vi screen:

If I understand this correctly, I need to select an option from the list and enter it somewhere. In my case I believe I want to drop commit a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597. So with vi I can just press i and enter interactive mode, however once I get there, I have absolutely no idea what to do.
I'm assuming I want to do something like drop a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597, but not sure where to write that in the file.
And then, once I have the correct changes applied, do I just hit :wq! and then "Enter", and git will execute the rebase command for me? Or do I need to do something else. Do I need to commit or push afterwards to propagate my local changes up to GitHub?
Update
I followed one user's advice and ran:
git rebase -i a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597^

Which brought me to this screen:

I deleted the line:

And then pressed :wq! and then hit enter, and saw this:
zharvey@Zacs-MacBook-Pro gh-purge-history-troubleshooting % git rebase -i a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597^
Auto-merging config.properties
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config.properties
error: could not apply 5d52a45... redacting
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 5d52a45... redacting

I then resolved conflicts manually and hit Save in VS Code:

And then tried doing git add . -n and then git commit -m <messag> but am now seeing:
zharvey@Zacs-MacBook-Pro gh-purge-history-troubleshooting % git commit -m "resolving merge conflicts after redacting"
U   config.properties
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

This feels waaaaayy more complicated then it needs to be. Can someone spoonfeed me the exact commands I need to run and provide a simple explanation for what each one does? I just want the values redacted and the bad commit removed from history.

Your interactive rebase does not involve a04cec8a225cdd1cf64989ca47f582f4e51e7597 because with git rebase <commit> you specify the parent commit of the earliest commit you want to change. This is not an issue with how to edit the rebase instructions file or with how to use Vim.

You want to run git rebase -i <commit that introduced the password>^ (note the trailing ^ after the commit id). This means "the parent of the commit that introduced the passwords". You will then see the erroneous commit in the pick list, and you can simply delete that line.

(BTW instead of creating a second commit and then deleting the first commit you could also have amended the first commit. It amounts to the same result but the author date of the original commit would be preserved.)

Thanks @mkrieger1 but I followed your advice and its not working and I may have made things worse. Please see my updates.

After resolving the conflict, use git rebase --continue, not git commit. Otherwise you will create an additional commit again.

OK thanks, but when I run git rebase --continue it tells me: config.properties: needs merge You must edit all merge conflicts and then mark them as resolved using git add.

And indeed you must. That is what happens during a merge conflict. This is how Git works.

OK I realized that after I Saved my config.properties file, I only ran git add . -n, not git add .. So I ran git add ., then ran git rebase --continue and got a message: Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature/some-feature. So then I run git push and am now getting error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/bitbythecron/gh-purge-history-troubleshooting.git'.

Because you rebased. You have to push with force now; you've changed history. That's what rebasing is.

Yep, OK, makes sense, so help me cross the finish line here: would that be git rebase --force feature/some-feature?

You are not rebasing now. You are pushing.

Sorry, git push --force feature/some-feature @matt?

If git push alone worked before, I would say git push --force now. In other words, whatever you did before, do it now with force. Don't complicate things by adding or subtracting anything.

Out of curiosity, why are you using :wq! instead of just :wq when exiting vim? Are you expecting the write to fail (e.g. because the file is readonly)? If so, the solution is probably to fix the reason you can't write to the file, not overriding the exit with !.

With regards to force pushing, using just push --force has a non-zero change of causing trouble unless you are super careful. You are much better of creating a forcepush alias with some safer options, see [this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) for details.

Here was the solution in my case, for any aftercomers:

git rebase -i <commit-I-wish-to-purge>^
In vi, press i to enter interactive mode. Then delete the entire line at the top describing the commit you want to delete. Then do :wq! and press enter.
Resolve conflicts manually (I used VS Code but any editor will do) and save them
git add .
git rebase --continue
git push --force


To delete a line in Vim, you don't need to enter insert mode. Just press dd as the command to delete the current line.
